# Search filter using contact name and number

Tags: android

I want to make a searching filter which can search name or number from my contact list coming from mySQL.

I have prepared one adapter in which I pass contacts in array list:

```
if (books.size() > 1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        if (i != (books.size() - 1)) {
            if (!books.get(i).get("contact_name").toString().equals(books.get(i + 1).get("contact_name").toString())) {
                UniqueBooks.add(books.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            UniqueBooks.add(books.get(i));
        }
    }
} else {
    UniqueBooks = books;
}


Books = UniqueBooks;
mStringFilterList = UniqueBooks;
```

and for filtering contact, I have done which searches contact by name.

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {


//Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

        ArrayList> filterList = new ArrayList>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
            String contactNo = (String) mStringFilterList.get(i).get("contact_name");
            contactNo = contactNo.toLowerCase();
            constraint = (CharSequence) constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            //System.out.println("contactNo "+contactNo+ " char "+constraint);
            if (contactNo.contains(constraint)) {
                filterList.add(mStringFilterList.get(i));
            }
        }


        results.count = filterList.size();

        results.values = filterList;

    } else {

        results.count = mStringFilterList.size();

        results.values = mStringFilterList;

    }

    return results;
}
```

Is there a way to filter contact by name and number together?

Comment: Yes, change this line if (contactNo.contains(constraint)) to if (contactNo.contains(constraint)||(contactName.contains(constraint)) , hope this helps

Comment: why don't you implement specific method in your content provider to do the work for you and query your database with given selection arguements?

Comment: Is mStringFilterList static?

Comment: @Nisarg I had checked with contactName.contains(const‌​raint) way but it is giving me IndexOutofBound error

Comment: @Ray Hong No, mStringFilterList is array and it is not declared as static

Comment: @MehranZamani Not getting you Can you please explain more?

Comment: how do you retrieve your data from database? with queries, right? so change the query so that if you want to search, give it a contact and it does the work for you and respond

Comment: Yeah, I retrieved contact data using queries and store it in arraylist using Hashmap type then pass out that array in my custom adaptor and filtering contact from there. and I am using Recycler List view and i think it is not supporting cursor adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in contact_name, contact_no or any other queries as a `query`.
Overriding may fail so you could make it as a function.

If you want to filter contact by name and number together, then you just have to call the function twice like:

```
valuefilter.filter_result = valuefilter.performFiltering("constraint", "contact_name");
valuefilter.filter_result = valuefilter.performFiltering("constraint", "contact_no");
```

I cannot tell how you are getting `mStringFilterList`. From my best understanding of your code above, this would minimize changing your code struct.

```
FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint, String query) {
//...
    for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
        String contactNo = (String) mStringFilterList.get(i).get(query);
        //...
    }
//...

return results;
}
```

Comment: @Roy Thanks, It is working for my BaseAdapter but For Recycler View it it is not working. Do you have any idea for making it working on Recycler view?

Comment: Post a new question with your Recyclerview code please and link me here. I have a feeling that it would be a different problem.